# Horizontal alignment of CSS sub-submenu?

Tags: html, css

I have created a nested menu with the ul/li tags and I would like to horizontally align the second and the third sub-submenu to the first submenu.

Visually, I have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TctL.png
and I want this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehP2G.png

CSS/HTML:

```css
 body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 1.6vw;
  color: #FFF;
}
div#header {
  width: 65vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#nav {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
}
#nav ul {
  display: inline-table;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}
#nav ul li a {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 7px;
  border-color: #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li .active {
  color: #F00;
  border-left-color: #F00;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #F00;
  border-color: #F00;
}
#nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 0.85em
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>

          <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a>

              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>

              <ul id="sub2">
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 5</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 7</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a>

              <ul id="sub3">
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 10</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </li>

          </ul>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The only idea I came up with is to manually move the margin to the left by adding this:

```css
#nav ul li:hover ul li:hover ul#sub2  {
 margin-left: -10.8vw
}

#nav ul li:hover ul li:hover ul#sub3 {
 margin-left: -21.5vw
}
```

I thought that using "vw" as unit is a good idea because I have a 16:9 monitor (resolution: 1366x768) and I assumed it would scale on other 16:9 monitors but tests on other resolutions show that the sub-submenu's are either more to the left or still a bit to the right of the first submenu. Is it possible to handle this problem with minor modifications or would I have to rewrite the whole thing by using, for example fixed sizes in pixels ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply try adding this:

```
#nav ul li ul li ul {
  left: 0;
}
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/d8hrcxmr/2/

If you ever need all the sub menus appear to the very left check out this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/d8hrcxmr/1/

```
#nav ul li ul {
  left: 0;
}
```

I think this is better for solving the problem of sub menus get cut off on the right (Imagine you have long sub menus on Menu6).

Comment: Ok, this was easy and painless. You are also right regarding the sub menus, I added the style to "#nav ul li ul" just to be sure. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You have do use `left` to move sub menu to left edge of its containing element. 
Here is the working example of your desired result

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6vw;
  color: #FFF;
}
div#header {
  width: 65vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#nav {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
}
#nav ul {
  display: inline-table;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}
#nav ul li a {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 7px;
  border-color: #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li .active {
  color: #F00;
  border-left-color: #F00;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #F00;
  border-color: #F00;
}
#nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 0.85em
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <div id="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="active">Menu 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>

          <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a>

              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 1</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 2</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>

              <ul id="sub2">
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 3</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 4</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 5</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 6</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 7</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </li>

            <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a>

              <ul id="sub3">
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 8</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 9</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Subsubmenu 10</a>
                </li>
              </ul>

            </li>

          </ul>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's pretty simple.just add the
 `#nav ul li ul li ul {
  left: 0;
}` to your css code.

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 1.6vw;
  color: #FFF;
}
div#header {
  width: 65vw;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#nav {
  font-size: 1.4em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
}
#nav ul {
  display: inline-table;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0px;
  border-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
#nav ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}
#nav ul li a {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-left-width: 7px;
  border-color: #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li .active {
  color: #F00;
  border-left-color: #F00;
}
#nav ul li a:hover {
  color: #F00;
  border-color: #F00;
}
#nav ul li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul li ul {
  display: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 0.85em
}
#nav ul li ul li ul {
  left: 0;
}
```